# Android CardView doesn't set the correct colors

Tags: java, android

there is an issue with my CardView, I have it in a RecyclerView, everything is working well but the color that I set for the CardViews aren't the same that I chose

Comment: What is the colour that you expect?

Comment: Something else.

Comment: Given the color it seems you might be passing in a color resource ID instead of a color int, try resolving the color with `ContextCompat.getColor(context, thisObject.getColor())`

Comment: Glad i was able to help, posting as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the color it seems you might be passing in a color resource ID instead of a color int, try resolving the color with:

```kotlin
ContextCompat.getColor(context, thisObject.getColor())
```